# ECS ec2 instance with user data

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

To launch docker-compose, I use AWS ECS.

When create cluster, ec2 instance automatically launched.

And can't launch with none instance. Must have at least 1 instance.

To time sync(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html), I have to execute shell script before ec2 instance running.

I searched google few hours, there is no correct answer.

Is there any solution to launch cluster with user data?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this really something you need to worry about with ECS? The underlying EC2 instances should be abstracted to the point where you don't need to worry about this sort of thing.

Comment: @deceze I don't understand what exactly you said.

Comment: Does your Docker instance have any issues with time? Why do you think you need to worry about this at all?

Comment: @deceze Because of leap second.

Comment: Is there an issue with leap seconds in ECS containers…?

Comment: @deceze Not yet. But to prevent that issue. refer this -> https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/aws/keeping-time-with-amazon-time-sync-service/

Comment: See https://github.com/azavea/terraform-aws-ecs-cluster/issues/25; AWS should already be taking care of that.

Comment: @Hide have you found a solution to this question? This is exactly what I want to do too.